# How to programmatically call a next.js api that uses next-auth

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, next-auth

I have a next.js app using next-auth. Next-auth is configured to use facebook and google as providers.

The app also have a few endpoints in the pages/api folder. These endpoints are used from the standard next.js pages. To protect endpoints I use this function:

```
const {getSession} = require("next-auth/react");

async getAuthenticatedUser(req) {
  const session = await getSession({req});
  if (!session) {
    return false;
  }
  const email = session.user.email;
  const user = await this.findUser({email: email});
  if (!user || user.isActive === false) {
    return false;
  }
  return user;
}
```

I would like to know if there is a way to programmatically authenticate to next-auth using a provider, in order to programmatically call an endpoint.

Answer (score 0):

You can try add providers and then save them to session
[image]